# How to fix 404 error installing updates?

Tags: apt, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I am not able to install any software on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system.

Here is the output of `sudo apt-get update`

```
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise InRelease                             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                 
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                           
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                               
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease                        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease                      
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease                      
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner amd64 Packages                
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                 
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg                      
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                 
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release                        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex    
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex      
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en      
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main amd64 Packages            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted amd64 Packages      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe amd64 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_US             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en        
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/lucid-bleed/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/lucid-bleed/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/lucid-bleed/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to disable entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` that match `lucid-bleed`, since they are the ones giving errors.

Comment: mammadori, thanks for the reply, but now its giving the following error.......W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise/partner amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems

Comment: @Dipesh Please *edit your question* to add this information, as it's very hard to read as a comment. Also, in a Terminal window please run `lsb_release -a; echo; cat /etc/apt/sources.list; for X in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*; do echo; echo; echo "** $X:"; echo; cat $X; done`. That will show detailed information about all configured software sources. Then select all the text from the Terminal starting with the line where you pasted in that command, copy and paste into your question, and use the `<$>` tool to give the block code highlighting (then the `http://`s won't be rejected).